# Найти количество полупутей в бинарном дереве поиска

Tags: алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

```
 Здравствуйте! Нужна небольшая помощь с алгоритмами.
```

Суть задачи заключается в следующем. **Нам дано бинарное дерево поиска. Необходимо в нем найти кол-во полупутей наибольшей длины.**

Полупуть - это чередующаяся последовательность вершин и дуг. Очень важное уточнение - направление дуг не играет никакой роли, т.е. мы можем начать наше движение, условно говоря, от какого-нибудь листа. Полупуть наибольшей длины - это полупуть, в котором наибольшее количество дуг.

Я придумал незамысловатый алгоритм, правда он работает только для путей(тоже самое, что и полупуть, только направление дуг играет значение)

Собственно, сам алгоритм:

1. Каждой вершине дерева ставим в соответствие метку

   а)Если вершина - лист, то метка равна 0.

   б)Если вершина не лист, то метка равна высоте данной вершины
2. Далее каждой вершине мы должны поставить еще новую метку:
    Новая метка = сумма старых меток сыновей вершины.

3.Ищем вершины, у которых метки имеют максимальную величину - именно эти вершины являются корнями путей (корень пути - вершина пути, которая имеет максимальную высоту)

Приведу пример: пусть у нас задано бинарное дерево поиска

10, 30, 180, 181, 20, 70, 60, 50, 40, 130, 176, 177, 178, 179, 120, 110, 100, 90

По написанному мною алгоритму, мы найдем только 1 вершину  - 10.
Она будет корневой для 2 полупутей (это легко будет проверить - от корней вершины по циклу пойдем по тому сыну, у кого старая метка больше. Если старые метки равны, то это и означает, что существует 2 полупути наибольшей длины).

Однако, по факту, должно быть еще 2 вершины - это вершина 30 (для нее один полупуть) и вершина 130 (для нее тоже 1 полупуть)

В итоге, при помощи моего алгоритма можно найти только 2 полупути, а в реальности их 4. Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться с этой проблемой.

Основные определения по бинарным деревьям можно посмотреть тут:

https://acm.bsu.by/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

Из-за своей невнимательности я совершил фатальную ошибку. Задача корректно решается, если листы нумеровать единицами,а не нулями. Тогда корни полупутей находятся корректно

Answer (score 0):

Дерево отличается тем, что между двумя вершинами (в данном случае - листьями) путь единственный.

Так что метод  - не оптимальный, наверное, но простой -  находим матрицу кратчайших путей между всеми вершинами любым способом, считаем в ней количество максимальных значений, делим пополам.

Альтернатива - выполнить BFS обход из корня, определив вершины с наибольшей глубиной, затем из этих вершин выполнить BFS обходы (как делается для определения диаметра дерева)